# What does this plot signify?

Tags: statistics

Well I am totally new to box plots and here is a boxplot I generated using Matlab for a certain software project.
I am asked to tell the significance of the box plot, and well, I don't know what it is!
The plots are link quality between certain ip addresses and here's what a link quality is:
[image]

Here is the generated plot:

[image]
Okay, I know this question is naive but this isn't really my field of expertise. What am I missing? How do the plots compare, what they signify?

Thanks.

Comment: Blox plot is a way to represent given data in which you visualize the median, the maximum and the minimum values, second and third quartiles and the outliers in the data. You can search the internet to look for the details and to find out  what each of those is on the graph.  Look for example [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Box-and-Whisker-Plot). If the data set is large enough It provides information on the distribution of the data.